# Creating Beveled Edges Without Using a Filter

Tags: inkscape

If you look at the below image you will see that the the edges of the box at the lower left corner where the arrow goes through it are beveled. Note that not the entire box is beveled:

[image: Logo Beveled]

Does anyone have an idea as to how I can recreate these beveled edges? I tried creating a white path following those edges and then blurring it, but of course the blur bleeds over the edge of the box, which is a problem because in my design the black area is transparent and thus if you place the image over a dark background you will see the blur bleed over. See below for my design:

[image]

Comment: I don't see how it would be possible using your design. Since you have a transparent middle square, there's nothing for the bevel to have contrast against. You would have a white bevel against a white background which wouldn't look like a bevel.  It only works as a bevel illusion on top example with the black middle square because of that contrast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

White isn't especially useful for beveling if you have a white background. But if you also have the dark side and the background isn't totally white, it's worth a try. I put a grey background to see all well in this demonstration.

You can also use something colored instead of white, if it matches with your art.

[image]

1. A test shape, resembles a little one of your shapes. Lets call it "Shape" here.
2. make a copy of Shape, no fill, solid white (or black) stroke. Actually you need total 3 versions of Shape. Lock and hide those which aren't under work. Use the objects panel for easily controlled selections.
3. With the node tool insert some nodes. You must have a node in every place where dark and lighted bevels fade to each other. Select those nodes, in the node tool info bar click "Break path at selected nodes". Confirm it with Path > Break apart.

[image]

4. Recolor the path segments to bevel shading colors. Group them.

5.Insert (=unhide) a copy of Shape, lower it to the bottom

6. Blur the bevel group
7. Insert a copy of Shape to the top, select it and the bevel group, goto Object > Clip > Make to remove the exessive blurred bevel.

You can reduce the blur, increase stroke widths or duplicate the bevel group to make it stronger. Grouping and the clipping mask do not prevent selecting and editing. Beware: You can easily get totally lost if you accidentally move something to invisibility under the clipping mask.

Here the bevel group is duplicated:

[image]

Blurring may not be a good idea, if you want to make a general SVG export to another software. Here's an alternative. It uses gradients:

[image]

Bevel area is divided with the node tool to segments differently. Black is the shadow, green gets transition gradient from shadow to light and the cyan will be the light.

In the middle the bevel coloring is done.

In the right Shape copy is added to the bottom and another copy has been used to clip the grouped bevel.

The result hasn't the rounded appearance of the blur.

**Add due a comment:**

Inkscape effect support varies in other software - Blur isn't an exception:

This is drawn in Inkscape 0.92.2 - a rectangle and a copy with blur:

[image]

this was saved 2 times - as Inkscape SVG and as a general SVG. Both opened in Inkscape ok.

Both opened in Illustrator as follows:

[image]

Illustrator is a pre-CC version. New Illustrator can be better.

Comment: This looks amazing @user287001! I’m going to try it now. What do you mean by “Blurring may not be a good idea, if you want to make a general SVG export to another software”?

Comment: @ReginaldGreyling Blurred shapes can lose the blur in another software or it can be rasterized. I added an example to my answer.The situation is same for any effect. Nothing quarantees that it's understood. My illustrator is a legacy one., Newer version can be better. Web browsers also can support things differently.

Comment: Ah I see @user287001. One last question before I accept your answer: what did you use to export the above images?

Comment: @ReginaldGreyling The version was Inkscape 0.92.2 (5c3e80d, 2017-08-06)

Comment: from my side, thank you for your excellent assistance and for all the effort you put into your answer. I really appreciate the help.